# How to create a file in query with read and write permission for all users in mysql 8

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

When I run this query on mysql 5.7:

```
SELECT CURDATE() INTO OUTFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/test.csv';
```

It creates `test.csv` with the following permissions:

```
-rw-rw-rw- 1 mysql mysql        11 Mar 18 04:27 test.csv
```

But when I create the same file in mysql 8.0 it creates file with the following permissions:

```
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql    11 Mar 18 09:54 test.csv
```

How would I allow mysql 8 to create file with the same permissions it created with mysql 5.7 ? The reason being I need to read and write to that generated file later in my application.

Comment: What specific version of 8 are you using?

Comment: my mysql version is 8.0.28

Answer (score 0):

From the Changelog:

> ----- 2019-07-22 8.0.17 General Availability -- -- -----
>
> The umask for files created using [SELECT ... INTO
> OUTFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html) or
> [SELECT ... INTO
> DUMPFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html)
> was changed from 0666 to 0640. The
> [LOAD_FILE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file)
> function no longer requires files to be world-readable, just readable
> by the server. (Bug #24513720)

(Unfortunately, Oracle does not let us see that bug report.)

Comment: ok but you didn't suggested any solution.

Comment: Is there a reason you cant change the umask in your application ?